# mockito unit testing Wanted but not invoked:

Tags: junit, mockito, tdd

I have seen there are similar question already exist in SO , I tried all the solution , but couldn't fix my problem , as I am new to `tdd`

I have a class like this

```
public class AppUpdatesPresenter  {

    public void stopService() {
        ServiceManager.on().stopService();
    }
}
```

I have the test class like this

```
@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)
public class AppUpdatesPresenterTest {
       @Mock
       AppUpdatesPresenter appUpdatesPresenter;

       @Mock
       ServiceManager serviceManager;

       @Mock
       Context context;

       @Test
       public void test_Stop_Service() throws Exception {
            appUpdatesPresenter.stopService();
            verify(serviceManager,times(1)).stopService();
       }

}
```

When I tried to test that , if I call `stopService()` method , then `ServiceManager.on().stopService();` called at least once .

But I am getting the following error

```
Wanted but not invoked:
serviceManager.stopService();
-> at io.example.myapp.ui.app_updates.AppUpdatesPresenterTest.test_Stop_Service(AppUpdatesPresenterTest.java:103)
Actually, there were zero interactions with this mock.
```

Not sure whats gone wrong .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you call `appUpdatesPresenter.stopService();`, nothing happened as you didn't tell it what should be happened.

To make your test pass, you need stubbing the `appUpdatesPresenter`.

```
@Test
public void test_Stop_Service() throws Exception {
    doAnswer { serviceManager.stopService(); }.when(appUpdatesPresenter).stopService()
    appUpdatesPresenter.stopService();
    verify(serviceManager).stopService();
}
```

Btw, the **above test is meaningless** as you stub all the things.

---

To make the test case meaningful, you should **inject** the `ServiceManager` instead of coupling it with `AppUpdatePresenter`.

```
public class AppUpdatesPresenter  {
    private final ServiceManager serviceManager;

    public AppUpdatesPresenter(ServiceManager serviceManager) {
        this.serviceManager = serviceManager;
    }

    public void stopService() {
        sm.stopService();
    }
}
```

Then make the `AppUpdatesPresenter` under test.

```
@InjectMock AppUpdatesPresenter appUpdatesPresenter;
```

Now the test case doesn't rely on canned interaction but real implementation of your code.

```
@Test
public void test_Stop_Service() throws Exception {
    appUpdatesPresenter.stopService();
    verify(serviceManager).stopService();
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for you answer 

But in my case the `ServiceManager` class is singletone , what can I do in this case ?